# Can't add image to AWS Autoscale launch config

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ec2-ami

I'm using the following command to set up the AWS launch config:

```
as-create-launch-config test1autoscale --image-id ami-xxxx --instance-type m1.small
```

where ami-xxxx is the image id that I got from my instance via the web console. I get the following error:

```
Malformed input-AMI ami-xxxx is invalid: The AMI ID 'ami-xxxx' does not exist
```

I have triple checked that the image id matches the instance image id. My availability zone is ap-southeast-1a. I am not clear on what image is being asked for if it will not accept the image of the instance I wish to add to the autoscale group

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding the region endpoint (because by default it's looking into us-east-1 enpoint) to your config command, then it should work:

```
as-create-launch-config test1autoscale --region ap-southeast-1 --image-id ami-xxxx --instance-type m1.small
```

Also take a look at this: [Regions and Endpoints - Amazon Web Services Glossary](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#as_region)

Comment: The problem is probably due to the wrong region. Also, don't forget to change the API endpoint, either by using -U http :// xxx or by setting AWS_AUTO_SCALING_URL environment variable (export AWS_AUTO_SCALING_URL=http :// ... ,at least on Linux). Don't forget the http or https in the url. [Note that the address must be without spaces. I had to put them because otherwise addresses are transformed into links :-)]